# Android - ImageView as header

Tags: android, imageview, screen

I want to display an image on top of my activity that always fill the screens width. If I set its width to match parent and its height to wrap content there is a white stripe at the sides of the image on larger screen. How can I make that this image always fill the screen horizontally?

My xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
    android:src="@drawable/tbbt" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your layout xml.

Comment: you can try by adding `android:scaleType="fitXY" attribute to your `ImageView`.

Comment: It works but it just undraw the image and doesnt maintain the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change imageview to fit the complete screen width

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

or

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Comment: Try android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Comment: Now it crops the edges of the picture.

Comment: Yes. If you need to maintain the same resolution across, create 9-patch background http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html